# Start Chromium without starting Desktop (LXDE)

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium

is it possible to start Chromium without starting Desktop on Raspberry Pi?

I am able to start Medori by editing $HOME/.xinitrc and writing in Medori but for some reasons it is not possible to start Chromium.

The output is something like that:
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
[1:1:1234563078:ERROR:nss_util.cc(692)] Failed to load NSS libraries
Created new window in existing browser session.
xinit: connection to X server lost

**Update:**

Refering to a comment from [here](http://lokir.wordpress.com/2012/09/16/raspberry-pi-kiosk-mode-with-chromium/), it seems to be possible to start Chromium without start LXDE.

Ass the comment discribed:

Edit /home/myuser/.xinitrc

```
unclutter -idle 15 -root &
xset -dpms &
xset s off &
exec chromium -incognito -kiosk “http://your.web.site”
```

Edit /etc/rc.local

```
su – myuser -c “startx” &
exit 0
```

However, the error still exists,
*[1:1:1234563078:ERROR:nss_util.cc(692)] Failed to load NSS.*

Can I reinstall this libraries, give it any permission to start without LXDE or something like that?

THX

Comment: I know this old but maybe this helps related to the NSS issue: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/11963

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but then realised I need to place the call within a loop. This is what I am using and it works fine.

```
# Disable DPMS.
xset -dpms

while true; do

        # Clean up previously running apps, gracefully at first then harshly
        killall -TERM chromium 2>/dev/null;
        killall -TERM matchbox-window-manager 2>/dev/null;

        sleep 2;

        killall -9 chromium 2>/dev/null;
        killall -9 matchbox-window-manager 2>/dev/null;

        # Launch window manager without title bar.
        exec matchbox-window-manager -use_titlebar no &

        # Launch browser.
        chromium --incognito --kiosk http://mammothworkwear.com

done;
```

Also note the command line options start with a double hyphen --

Comment: Can you please outline with the realisation you did, what is the rationale behind the loop?

Comment: The loop is used so if your chromium crashes, it is cleaned up and restarted.  The execution pauses on the last "chromium" line, until it closes/crashes.  Then it repeats the kill processes and restarts.

Comment: I keep getting the error "Cannot Open Display" check display varaible